# While writing the command to get the storage account key.There will be two keys,how to store a value in variable

Tags: azure, azure-storage

`az storage account keys list -g <resourcegroupname> -n <accountname>`

```
[
  {
    "keyName": "key1",
    "permissions": "Full",
    "value": "<key1value>=="
  },
  {
    "keyName": "key2",
    "permissions": "Full",
    "value": "<key2value>=="
  }
]
```

Comment: Welcome! I'm unsure I understand your question. But also: it appears you shared your real storage account name and keys (I edited your keys, as well as your storage account name). Note that, if those were indeed real keys, you should regenerate them asap - anyone with enough reputation can still see the original post and hijack your storage account.

Comment: There will be two keys right I want to store one key value in a new variable  can you how to do it

Comment: `az` is a command-line tool, so there are no variables in the code sense. Have you considered storing the results as an environment variable? You can also look into other command-line tools such as `jq` to parse the returned data to extract exactly what you need. I would suggest looking at that tool and trying it out.

Answer (score 0):

`--query` is used to execute a JMESPath query on the results of commands. The `--query` argument is supported by all commands in the Azure CLI.  You could [get properties in an array](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest#get-properties-in-an-array) by this.

```
key=$(az storage account keys list -g <resourcegroupname> -n <accountname> --query '[<index>].<parameter>')

echo $key
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, @Manoj Bhargav. Is my reply helpful for your issue?

Answer (score 0):

To extract the first key and store it in a variable, you can use the following command:

```
var=$(az storage account keys list -g rgname -n  storagAccName -o json --query "[0].value")
```